# convert TreeMap<String,Object> to List<HashMap<String,Object>>

Tags: list, collections, java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I have a `TreeMap<String,Object>` which contains Objects that are actually `HashMap<String,Object>`. I want to convert this to `List<HashMap<String,Object>>`. I was trying to convert it using Java 8 and wrote the following code which is giving compilation error due to conversion from `List<Object>` to `List<HashMap<String,Object>>`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        TreeMap<String,Object> treeMap = new TreeMap<String,Object>();
        HashMap<String,Object> map1 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map1.put("a",1);
        map1.put("b","2");
        map1.put("c",5);
        treeMap.put("01",map1);
        HashMap<String,Object> map2 = new HashMap<String,Object>();
        map2.put("a",5);
        map2.put("b","7");
        map2.put("c",6);
        treeMap.put("02",map2);

//this conversion is not working as Java is not allowing to convert from List<Object> to List<HashMap<String,Object>>
        List<HashMap<String,Object>> list= treeMap.values().stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

Changing the TreeMap to `TreeMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>>` works but I don't want to make this change as I am passing this to a separate method which expects `TreeMap<String,Object>`.

Please suggest.

Comment: Can you change the other method parameter from `TreeMap<String,Object>` to `TreeMap<String,?>` (equivalent to `? extends Object`)? That would let you pass in a `TreeMap<String,HashMap<String,Object>>`.

Comment: why would you not change the definition to be correct to begin with. this `Object` is only going to cause deeper and deeper problems...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you define the `treeMap` to have `Object` values, this is why `values().stream()` returns a `Stream<Object>`. Either change your contract or you'll need to cast the elements in the stream:

```
List<HashMap<String,Object>> list= treeMap.values().stream()
    .map(element -> (HashMap<String,Object>)element)
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Since this bears an *unchecked* operation anyway, you can simplify the whole thing to `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") List<HashMap<String,Object>> list = new ArrayList(treeMap.values());`…

Answer (score 1):

I would start by giving `treeMap` the proper types: `TreeMap<String, HashMap<String, Object>>`.

You can then wrap the map and pass `new TreeMap<String, Object>(treeMap)` to that other method.

Nicer, as it does not require a new map, would be to follow Sean's comment and change that method's parameter from `TreeMap<String, Object>` to `TreeMap<String, ?>`, if you are allowed to do that.

Comment: Thanks, I wanted to avoid this route as didn't want to make any modification to existing code. Anyhow took your advice and changed it now.